# Get the maximum value per group and elbow point of a sequence of values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let it be the following Python Panda DataFrame. I want for each `num_clusters` group, to keep the row with the highest calinski_harabasz score.

```
                              params num_clusters  calinski_harabasz 
0  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 2}            2        4209.697651  
1  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 2}            2        4209.697651    
2  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 3}            3        5334.854274  
3  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 3}            3        5436.854274 
4  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 4}            4        4702.497651   
5  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 4}            4        4709.697651   
6  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 5}            5        5636.855534    
7  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 5}            5        5736.854274
```

First resulting DataFrame: In case two rows have the same `num_clusters` and calinski value, delete any of them.

```
                              params num_clusters  calinski_harabasz 
0  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 2}            2        4209.697651    
3  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 3}            3        5436.854274  
5  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 4}            4        4709.697651    
7  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 5}            5        5736.854274
```

Then, assuming that the `num_cluster` values are sorted in ascending order. I will return the first row such that the next value is lower than its value.

```
                              params num_clusters  calinski_harabasz    
3  {'max_iter': 700, 'n_clusters': 3}            3        5436.854274
```

If I had the same problem but instead of the maximum you wanted to take into account the minimum, how would you do it? That is, in the first part, to keep the smallest of each group. In the second part, keep the value such that the next one is greater than the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
out = (df
   # min of each group
   .loc[df.groupby('num_clusters')['calinski_harabasz'].idxmin()]
   # score > to next one
   .loc[lambda d: d['calinski_harabasz'].gt(d['calinski_harabasz'].shift())]
   .head(1) # first row
)
```

output:

```
                               params  num_clusters  calinski_harabasz
2  {'max_iter': 200, 'n_clusters': 3}             3        5334.854274
```

Comment: Man this shift function really seens promising damm nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as good as @mozway (since he is literally a super computer in Silicon Valley haha), but this will also give you the results you want

```
df['Max'] = df.groupby('num_clusters')['calinski_harabasz'].transform(max)
df['Check'] = np.where(df['calinski_harabasz'] == df['Max'], True, False)
df = df.loc[df['Check'] == True]
df = df.groupby('num_clusters').first().reset_index()
df['Max_Shift'] = df['Max'].shift(-1)
df['Check'] = np.where(df['calinski_harabasz'] > df['Max_Shift'], True, False)
df = df.loc[df['Check'] == True]
df = df.groupby('Check').first().reset_index()
df
```